# How to convert JArray to String array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a JArray as below:

```
[
  {
    "iccid": "1",
    "quota": "500.00 MB"
  },
  {
    "iccid": "2",
    "quota": "500.00 MB"
  },
  {
    "iccid": "3",
    "quota": "500.00 MB"
  }
]
```

How to convert it into string array of the ICCID?, I expect to have a string array of the ICCID, like: ['1','2','3']

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `.Select()`,

```
List<string> result = jArray.Select(x => x.Value<string>("iccid")).ToList();
```

Output:

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

[.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/peaUVL)